# Telerik RadWindow won't open from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to open a radwindow from my code behind instead of using javascript. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

RadWindow Manager

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">

</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Control to open radwindow

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="PortChatButton" Text="Questions?" OnClick="PortChatClick" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void PortChatClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadWindow portChat = new RadWindow();
    portChat.Modal = true;
    portChat.ID = "PortingChatModal";
    portChat.NavigateUrl = "~/PortingChat.aspx";
    portChat.Style["z-index"] = "9999";
    portChat.AutoSize = true;
    portChat.VisibleTitlebar = false;
    portChat.VisibleStatusbar = false;
    portChat.Visible = true;
    RadWindowManager1.Windows.Add(portChat);
    portChat.Visible = true;
    return;
}
```

I don't understand why this doens't work.

Comment: I dont understand your comment. I don't think .show is a radwindow property. 

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/server-side-programming/properties

Comment: this may help you http://www.telerik.com/forums/want-to-pop-up-window-from-server-side#791040